# How does a regex match the format like xxxx1111 in js?

Tags: regex, vue.js

I'm limiting the user to input a string contains four letters following with 4 digit of numbers, like the format qwer1234 in vue.js. I have tried the regex `b[a-z]{4}+[0-9]{4}\b` but it seems not working. Are there any mistake I make?

Comment: you are missing 1 slash `\b[a-z]{4}+[0-9]{4}\b`. you could use this tool for testing your regular expressions https://rubular.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 lowercase characters would be:

- `[a-z]{4}`

4 digits would be

- `\d{4}`

a word boundary is

- `\b`

the start or end of a line are marked like this:

- `^...$`

So, if this phrase should be contained (possibly only as a part) of a bigger phrase, put word boundaries around it.

- `\b[a-z]{4}\d{4}\b`

or if the entire phrase has to match exactly, then you can put it between start and end characters.

- `^[a-z]{4}\d{4}$`

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the '+', and it works!

```
var pattern = /\b[a-z]{4}[0-9]{4}\b/;
var str = "";
console.log(pattern.test(str));
```